# AccessViolationException with C++/CLI and native interop

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a CLI/C++ class that instantiates a native C++ object, then later calls a method on that object and has some data returned. I'm getting random AccessViolationExceptions and can't figure out what's going on. Here's a stripped down version of my code:

```
public ref class MyWrapper
{
public:
   MyWrapper()
   {
      nativeObject = new NativeObject();
   }          

   Object^ getData(String^ field)
   {
      string nativeField = msclr::interop::marshal_as<string>(field);
      Data nativeResult = nativeObject->getData(nativeField);
      Object^ result = convertToManaged(nativeResult);
      return result;
   }

   Object& convertToManaged(Data data)
   {
       // This converts the char* noted below back into its basic data type, and returns it as an object
   }

private:
      NativeObject* nativeObject;
}
```

..then, in NativeObject...

```
Data getData(string nativeField)
{
      // do some processing
      Data result(nativeField);
      result.addData();
      return result;
}
```

A rough definition of Data:

```
class Data
{
private:
   string field;
   int dataType;
   char* dataArray;
   size_t size;

public:
   Data()
   {
      dataArray = NULL;
   }
   Data(const Data &value) 
   {
      copyData(value);
   }

   ~Data()
   {
      delete dataArray;
   }

   void copyData(const Data &value)
   { 
      dataType = value.dataType;
      size = value.size;

      if (value.dataArray != NULL)
      {
         dataArray = new char[value.size];
         memcpy(dataArray, value.dataArray, value.size);
      }
      else
      {
         dataArray = NULL;
      }
   }

   Data& Data::operator=(const Data & value)
   {
      copyData(value);
      return *this;
   }

   void addData()
   {
      /* This converts a basic data type like a double into a char* with reinterpret_cast, 
      like this: 

      double* newValue = new double();
      *newValue = value;
      dataArray = reinterpret_cast<char*>(newValue);
      size = sizeof(double);
      */
   }
}
```

Most of the time, this works fine. I have a C# test assembly that runs it with various (expected) input types and it runs without issue. But, when I put it in the context of a larger application, it will randomly throw AccessViolationExceptions. While most of them come from this code itself, it's not always the same place - sometimes its the managed getData function, sometimes its the native getData function. And ever stranger, when running with this code in place, random other parts of the application that are purely managed will give me AccessViolationExceptions, which never occurred before adding this code.

Any ideas what's going on? It seems obvious that I'm doing something bad to memory but I can't figure out what. I've tried a few variations of this (returning the native Data object as a pointer, creating the result object as a pin_ptr from the managed code, and passing it in as an argument, etc), but they all produce similar results.

Commenting out result.addData() APPEARS to make the issue go away. All that method does is allocate some memory that gets stored in the dataArray field. Could the fact that that's then passed back to managed code be the problem?

Comment: Google "c++ rule of three", you are violating it with the *dataArray* member.  The getData() function makes it fatal.  Might not be the only place.

Comment: Are you referring to my lack of copy constructor and destructor? I do have those - sorry, should have included them.

Comment: @Deeko - The rule of 3 also requires an assignment operator.  Second, your copy constructor is bogus.  It does nothing, and does not make a copy.  This bogus-ness is enough to cause issues with a program that makes copies, such as yours.

Comment: Can you explain what makes it bogus? I'm converting it back to a value type, creating a new pointer for the new object, and then putting that value in that pointer. Is there a step missing?

Comment: @Deeko - See my answer below.   Your copy constructor's responsibility is to *make copies*.  Your code refused to do that.

Comment: @Deeko -- Look at your copy constructor.  What if `value.dataArray` *is* NULL?  You never set it, thus you have a copy with an uninitialized pointer value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've simplified the copy constructor to copy the array and added NULL handling per your suggestions (thanks, it's cleaner and less error prone that way). Unfortunately, the AccessViolationExceptions persist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69765/discussion-between-paulmckenzie-and-deeko).

Answer (score 0):

The copy constructor you provided for your `Data` class is empty, thus anytime a copy is made, you are creating an object that is *not* a copy of the object you're copying.  What happens is that your program is now passing half-baked copies around with no `dataArray` element set.

These errors, where the user-defined copy constructor is broken or incomplete, are some of the toughest errors to diagnose.  You must complete your code for the copy constructor to perform a real copy.

In addition, you need an assignment operator to complete the "rule of 3".

Edit:  An example of a correctly coded copy constructor would be this:

```
   Data(const Data &value) : field(value.field), dataType(value.dataType), dataArray(0) 
   {
     addData(dataType, value.dataArray);
   }
```

And in the `addData` you determine the data type.

Additional information:

Your destructor need not check for NULL, as it is not necessary.

```
~Data()
{
    delete dataArray;
}
```

Also, the assignment operator would look like this:

```
   #include <algorithm>
   //...
   Data& operator=(Data value)
   {
      std::swap(value.dataType, dataType);
      std::swap(value.dataArray, datArraye);
      std::swap(value.field, field);
      return *this;
   }
```

Comment: It's not empty. The commented out section explains what it does. I could fill out the entire thing, but that would not be helpful. The Data class operates on different data types - and depending on certain inputs, it converts dataArray to/from different primitives. It doesn't add to the question to type all of it here, so I gave an example of what it does with doubles.

Comment: @Deeko - Please edit your question.  When you post code, all we are going by is what you post.  If we see no implementation, then there is no implementation.  And yes, it is important you post it because your code calls the copy constructor.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - I did post the code in the copy constructor, but in a comment, because it was not complete for every case. I've edited the original question to reflect this, but, like the new comment says - the "else" case does actually fill out dataArray, in the same way it does for doubles, just with other data types.

Comment: @Deeko - The copy constructor only responsibility is to create a copy.  I can't stress this any more than that.  Your implementation is dodgy, at best.  You shouldn't be doing any *if* statements at all -- just take the object passed to you, and create the *exact* copy of it.  If you don't do that, then my answer stands -- you're potentially passing around half-baked copies.

Comment: You updated your question with new code.  Your assignment operator is now faulty.  Please use the one I posted in the answer above.  Or better yet, use `std::vector<char>` and there will be no need for assignment op, copy constructor, or destructor.